# Extend Google Forms (Custom Functions)

Tags: google-forms

I ran into a bit of a problem here while creating a Google Form for work appraisals. I have the basic form for employees to fill out all set up but I need a second form for the heads of department to fill in employee scores.

Simply put:

1. User completes form
2. Completed form is forwarded to head of department for review
3. HoD finishes "grading" said form and submits to HR
4. Results are tabulated into Google Sheets for further use

Can this be solved with functions or add-ons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per stackoverflow rules: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

---

Having said that, I will be brief.
Yes. What you would need is just one form with a special workflow and the use of just one add-on.

I have prepared a functioning [Testing Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1ss-ZBlaCCxOpmJELtoxfpIZxvgMDzM2vrZhIDoTBW6E/viewform) for you. Please have look.
Make a note that the emailing ability has been disabled for obvious reasons.
Also. In the form a hint is provided for a password asked. Similar hint should be avoided in your working form.

***PS***: What to do when someone answers your question ([accepting and/or upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)) it.

Comment: Hi marikamitsos,

Thanks for the suggestion! I'll keep in mind regarding the rules.

The form you provided seems to be something close to what they're looking for. I'll go get the addon and mess around with it. Cheers!